# Why does index change in this specific sort of sum: $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{mx^m}{m!}=x\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I have an equation similar to the one below:

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { mx^m\over m!} $$

which naturally reduces to:

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^m\over (m-1)!} $$

and now for ***some reason*** we can do the following:

$$ = x \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} {x^{m-1}\over (m-1)!} $$

Why does the index increase? Is it just because we cannot evaluate $(m-1)!$   if $m=0$?

Note: if this works then we can shift the summation index to get that  $ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { mx^m\over m!} = xe^x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first term is zero.
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{mx^m}{m!}
 = \frac{0 x^0}{0!} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{m x^m}{m!}
 = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{(m-1)!}
 = x\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
 = x\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{m!}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your line of thought:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { mx^m\over m!}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^m\over (m-1)!}=x\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^{m-1}\over (m-1)!}=x\left(\frac{x^{-1}}{(-1)!}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} {x^{m-1}\over (m-1)!}\right)=\\
x\left(0+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^m\over m!}\right)=x\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^m\over m!}.$$
Note: $\frac{1}{\Gamma{(0)}}=\frac1{(-1)!}=0$. Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Particular_values).