# How can one show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}=e$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

> How can one show that  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}=e$?

I understand that 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x
$$
and that letting $x=1 $would give 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}=e
$$

But why does the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n!}$ give an answer of $e$ also?

Comment: In the picture on the bottom sum the numerator should be n, apologies.

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives ?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Do you want to prove: $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{x}{n!}=e?$

Comment: ‘No chance’ yes that was my question more or less, I just didn’t understand why different sums all add to e

Comment: It can be proven that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$. However, in your expression, you don't raise x to the power n.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2382928/11619) if not others as well (as pointed out by Xander Henderson in meta). I recommend against reopening, for it would only lead to being closed for another reason.

Comment: And if you are unhappy with that duplicate target, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2574668/11619) is an *exact* dupe.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $n/n!=1/(n-1)!$, which is not meaningfully distinct in the context of the infinite sum from the terms $1/n!$.

Answer (score 7):

In fact 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{n}{n!}\stackrel{(1)}{=}\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{n}{n!}=
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\stackrel{(2)}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!}=e^1=e
$$
(1) comes from the fact that the first term is zero, 
(2) is a shift of indices by one.

You can repeat this shifting procedure ad infinitum and obtain, for each fixed $k$
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{n(n-1)\ldots (n-k)}{n!}=e
$$
because your sum 'starts' at index $k+1$.

Comment: This is what I meant in my answer. Nice presentation. +1

Comment: So I, in fact, unfolded your idea ? (+1)

Comment: Teamwork! I like it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array} {rcl}
%
\displaystyle e^x & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
%
\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}e^x & = & \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
%
e^x & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} \\
%
e^1 & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n1^{n-1}}{n!} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response it’s really clear and perfectly understood, I appreciate it. So would I be right in assuming you can repeat this process ad infinitum and acquire many different expressions which all sum to e?

Comment: Yes, in this case the multipliers will be $$n,n(n-1),n(n-1)(n-2),\ldots$$ and so on ...

Comment: That’s incredibly interesting, aside from showing this with basic differentiation would you know where to find a geometric or more intuitive proof. The logic is perfectly reasonable but I prefer to see why.

Comment: @User3457884334 I added repetition of this process ad infinitum in my answer.

Comment: I understand that but wondered if there was another proof to show it geometrically.

Comment: IMHO no geometry here, but good combinatorics of operators. What does differentiation is a shifting of the indices, but you have this phenomenon for other operators on series as $$f(x)\to \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $e^x=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...$ try to find the constants by evaluating $e^0$ and then differentiating to eliminate the current $0$th degree term.

Here are the first three terms :
$$e^0=a_0+a_1*0+...=1\Leftrightarrow a_0=1$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)=e^x=\frac{d}{dx}(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+...$$
$$e^0=a_1+2a_2*0+3a_3*0^2+...=1\Leftrightarrow a_1=1$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)=e^x=\frac{d}{dx}(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+...)=2a_2+(3*2)a_3x+...$$
$$e^0=2a_2+(3*2)a_3*0\,+...=1\Leftrightarrow a_1=\frac{1}{2}$$
You'll find that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ switch $1$ for $x$ and you get your result (refer to The Count's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the series $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {x^n}{n!}$ term by term.  Get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {nx^{n-1}}{n!}$. Then set $x=1$.  Note that $(e^x)'=e^x$ (for$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {x^n}{n!}$) .